# Existe alguma maneira de rodar o Laravel, na linha de comando, em modo interativo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, artisan

No PHP, eu sei que é possível rodá-lo interativamente na linha de comando, que é através do comando `php -a`. Melhor ainda seria utilizando a biblioteca [`psysh`](http://psysh.org/).

Mas, em se tratando não apenas de rodar apenas simples testes, mas rodar uma aplicação interativamente na linha de comando, é possível fazer isso com o framework `Laravel`?

As versões 4 ou 5 possuem algum recurso que possibilitem isso? Tem como fazer isso pelo `artisan`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe uma maneira que funciona tanto para o `Laravel 4` quanto o `Laravel 5`.

Basta executar `php artisan tinker` na linha de comando

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nota**: A diferença entre os comandos no `Laravel 4` e `Laravel 5` é que o no `Laravel 5` usasse o `psysh`, que dispensa o uso do ponto-e-vírgula no final de cada sentença digitada na linha de comando (e é melhor também).

Comment: Faltou explicar que o próprio Laravel usa o psysh e o Laravel 4 usa outro cara... que não se limita a diferença somente do ponto e virgula que você comentou.